# Why FromBody Behave like this ?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to understand why FromBody behave like this for common request.

## Case 1:

**Controller**

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }
```

**POSTMAN Request**
[image]

**Problem**
In this case value is my post method will not bind to value parameter to test.

## Case 2:

**Model**

```
public class Test
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public void Post([FromBody]Test model)
        {
        }
```

**POSTMAN Request**
Same as Case 1

**Result :**
Now model value property successfully bind to "test".

Why it is behave like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that's the way the API was designed.  Note that in your second example you could have elided [FromBody] and WebApi would have searched the body for the data anyways because `Test` is a complex type.

This article explains the rules by which WebApi binds data:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

**EDIT:** As commented, the article linked above clearly states you should be able to do

```
void Get([FromBody]string value)
```

This **is** true, but it means you can read the value of the body as plain text into the parameter value.  This means if you go this route, you MUST use the raw option (from postman) and either clear Content-Type or make sure it's set to text/plain.

In other words, on Postman, if you set the send method to raw, and type in "this is a sentence" as is in the text area provided, your value, when the issue below is fixed, will be "this is a sentence".

Now, if you tried doing this from a fresh template, you will run into this error:

```
{
    "Message": "The request entity's media type 'text/plain' is not supported for this resource.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'text/plain'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

This article explains how to allow WebApi to accept text/plain data from the body:

https://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/c-supporting-textplain-in-an-mvc-4-rc-web-api-application/

It's kind of stupid that the default ValuesController exposes a method with that signature, but does not provide a MediaTypeFormatter for text/plain, but I guess that's Microsoft for you.

Comment: You are partial right but if in Case 1 if I pass Content-Type = application/json then it works why it is like that ? Even blog you suggested has following thing. void Action([FromBody] string name); // explicitly read the body as a string.

Comment: Thanks for second link. It is really helpful and find a way to understand thing.

Answer (score 0):

Given this method:

```
// POST api/values
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    Values.Add(value);
}
```

Postman must be configured correctly in order for our value to bind to its C# `string` object...one way to ensure this works in our case is to send our server a JSON request. Follow these steps:

- Make sure you've selected `POST`.
- Make sure you've entered an appropriate URL, i.e. `http://localhost:1337/api/values`.
- Go to `Body`, tick the option for `raw`.
- In the drop-down to the right, select `JSON (application/json)`.
- In the text area of Postman, insert only `"Hello, world."` (**with** the quotes as well, otherwise it won't be valid JSON).

It should now work once you hit `Send`.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON you can do this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Webhook(JToken json)
    {

    }
```

Where `JToken` is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`.

`JObject` works if the data is an actual JSON object (not an array)